# How long does it take for you to be comfortable with Haskell?

Tags: performance, haskell

I'm an OK C/C++ programmer. I find Haskell very intriguing. But it seems to me, that although it's relatively easy to write clean Haskell code, as it mimics math (which I'm very comfortable with) pretty well, it's very hard to write clean code in Haskell that runs fast.

A faster version of quicksort of Haskell is very long and scary, which has no resemblance to the naive but short (two lines), clean and intuitive implementation. The long and scary version of Haskell is actually still much slower than the shorter and simpler C counter part.

Is it because the current Haskell compiler is too dumb or is it just impossible for mortals (other than SJP of course) to write fast Haskell code?

Comment: I'd re-title your question as something like "Why do elegant Haskell programs run slower than ugly C programs?" The existing title is a too vague - at first I assumed you'd written a dumb question but it's actually great.

Comment: Well, the recursive version of C quicksort is not that ugly, which actually runs faster than the ugly version of Haskell.

Comment: It's hard to think of a wording that explains the question without sounding deliberately provocative. "Why is Haskell slow?" would sound like trolling, so I tried to even things out.

Comment: I'm asking the question in this manner to get broader perspectives from competent Haskell programmers, especially those who have C experiences.

Comment: The Haskell quicksort you're looking at is big and scary because it solves a different problem; quicksorting linked lists (as opposed to mutable arrays). If you looked at code for, say, sorting a Haskell `MVector`, it would look not unlike the c code.

Answer (score 61):

You ask two different questions: learning and performance.

- It took me about a month to become comfortable with functional programming using recursion, pattern matching, `map`, `filter`, and `fold`.  I did all that with ML but it translated to Haskell very easily.
- It took me two or three years to wrap my head around monads, but that's because I read the wrong stuff.  I think there are better tutorials now.  But if you're beginning, avoid monads for a while.
- It took me several months to get *good* at creating new type classes, but using the existing ones was easy.
- I'm still not sure I have the hang of **lazy evaluation**. But I love Haskell's **purity** and tend to treat lazy evaluation as an unhappy accident that only a few people (like John Hughes) know how to exploit.

You've observed a performance problem only because you've adapted an algorithm loaded with mutation, which Tony Hoare designed for imperative languages, and tried to translate into Haskell.  In Haskell as in any other functional language **the expensive operation is *allocation***.  Try writing a **merge sort** and you'll find it's **simple and performs very well.**

How do you avoid making similar mistakes in the future? Have a look at Chris Okasaki's book [Purely Functional Data Structures](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521663504).  Great book, and it will help you learn the 'functional way of doing things' without giving up performance.

Answer (score 22):

There is a very specific reason why quicksort ain't so quick in Haskell. It is a God-like example of an algorithm that has brilliant hackery woven into how it works - what I mean by hackery in this case is the kind of techniques that a true Haskell devotee would regard as unnecessarily dangerous and non-mathematical. The original implementation made every effort to break the rules that Haskell imposes on itself: the genuine quicksort works by overwriting storage slots with new information. This is very painful to do in Haskell, which finds it much easier to make whole new copies of existing information.

So although that naive two line Haskell version captures something of the essence of quicksort (it does the same number of key comparisons), it isn't really quicksort. It's missing a large portion of the genius that went into it, which took full advantage of the ability to tweak the state of existing values. So it makes large numbers of intermediate copies of pieces of the list.

Speculation: could a Haskell compiler analyze your code, applying the same reasoning as Hoare (inventor of quicksort) and figure out that it could optimize it by completely reimplementing it in a stateful way? Possibly.

Answer (score 13):

The point is not to write fast Haskell code, but to write Haskell code fast. When you get there and you need to make your code fast(er), start optimizing (or use the FFI, you don't have to forget your C++ skills). In Haskell you are looking for elegance, reliability and maintainability first.  I'd add profiling to my Haskell-fu, so you don't waste time optimizing that which is not used. And remember not to optimize prematurely.

Answer (score 8):

So, to answer the question in the title, you will likely feel fairly at home with the basics of Haskell within a short time.  Especially if you're already familiar with functional programming.  The things that really make Haskell stand out, such as laziness, type classes, type families, and of course the dreaded monads (and arrows) are likely to require more time to understand and get used to.  There are good resources for learning the language, many freely available, together with a helpful community, so I'd say you'd likely be well on your way to feeling comfortable within a week or two of semi-serious study ;-)

I think it's worth it though, just like some people argue that it's worth learning Lisp even if you'll never actually use it for anything.  It's worth it because it makes you a better programmer--it makes you think differently.  I'd argue Haskell has a similar effect.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that mathematical foundation of computers is different from mathematical foundation of Haskell and functional languages in general.

To get taste of problems compiler is facing... Translate Haskell program to C, keeping it as close to original as possible, then try to optimize that C code (without rewriting it from scratch in C-way)

It's not dumb, but functional languages are not made for performance, and concise mathematically simple notation doesn't come for free.

Comment: Not necessarily, see "Use those extra cores and beat C today!" for how easily Haskell parallelizes: http://cgi.cse.unsw.edu.au/~dons/blog/2007/11/29#smoking-4core

Comment: I don't see a disagreement here, parallel code in Haskell is really concise and easy to write, at the cost of performance. If limited time and resources let you write either single-threaded imperative or parallel functional code - that's the great use case for Haskell.

Comment: That example is so laughable! He uses a recursive fib in C which nobody would use, as an iterative version is simpler to write in C and much faster and will handily beat ANY Haskell implementation on 4 cores using only 1 core.

Comment: Um, the point is to compare a parallel and non-parallel implementations of the *same* algorithm -- that's just an example and Don Stewart does know better ways of writing a fibonacci function :p

Comment: Correction: *Haskell* is not made for performance. OCaml is widely recognized as one of the fastest languages in the world, with optimized code regularly performing at or beyond the speed of equivalent C.

Comment: Yes, but... OCaml wasn't made to be functional language. It has mutable types, side-effects, and allows imperative syntax features.

Comment: "OCaml is widely recognised as one of the fastest languages in the world" - on http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/ there is no appreciable difference between Haskell and OCaml and in many cases Haskell is faster. I think OCaml being faster than Haskell is now a misconception. Sure, this particular example could be done faster in OCaml with mutable data but that's not to say that OCaml is a faster functional language than Haskell.

Comment: @Juliet
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964392/speed-comparison-with-project-euler-c-vs-python-vs-erlang-vs-haskell
See the first answer.
Haskell wasn't originally made for performance, but unless the programmer is making all kinds of rookie mistakes Haskell will run at similar speeds to C.