# Coverting a recursive function to a tail recursive one in python

Tags: python, recursion, tail-recursion

As an exercise, i implemented the map function using recursion in python as follows:

```
#map function that applies the function f on every element of list l and returns the new list 
def map(l,f):
    if l == []:
        return []
    else:
        return [f(l[0])] + map(l[1:],f)
```

I am aware of the fact that python does not support tail recursion optimization, but how would i go about writing the same function in a tail recursive manner ?.

Please Help
Thank You

Comment: Why this function isn't tail recursive?

Comment: It isnt because map is not the last operation,the result of map is added to [f(l[0])], so every stack frame in the recursion process will be needed

Comment: Ok, so you recursively generate elements and then combine them to one list. Iterative process would update the state of list in every step and pass it to next iteration, right? Do you need more help?

Comment: Curiously, I have posted an answer about this yesterday! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964392/speed-comparison-c-vs-python-vs-erlang-vs-haskell/6964658#6964658

Answer (score 7):

Tail recursion means you must be directly returning the result of a recursive call, with no further manipulation.

The obvious recursion in map is to compute the function on one element of the list, then use a recursive call to process the rest of the list. However, you need to combine the result of processing one element with the result of processing the rest of the list, which requires an operation after the recursive call.

A very common pattern for avoiding that is to move the combination *inside* the recursive call; you pass in the processed element as an argument, and make it part of `map`'s responsibility to do the combining as well.

```
def map(l, f):
    if l == []:
        return []
    else:
        return map(l[1:], f, f(l[0]))
```

Now it's tail recursive! But it's also obviously wrong. In the tail recursive call, we're passing 3 arguments, but map only takes two arguments. And then there's the question of what do we do with the 3rd value. In the base case (when the list is empty), it's obvious: return a list containing the information passed in. In the recursive case, we're computing a new value, and we have this extra parameter passed in from the top, and we have the recursive call. The new value and the extra parameter need to be rolled up together to be passed into the recursive call, so that the recursive call can be tail recursive. All of which suggests the following:

```
def map(l, f):
    return map_acc(l, f, [])      

def map_acc(l, f, a):
    if l == []:
        return a
    else:
        b = a + [f(l[0])]
        return map_acc(l[1:], f, b)
```

Which can be expressed more concisely and Pythonically as other answers have shown, without resorting to a separate helper function. But this shows a general way of turning non-tail-recursive functions into tail recursive functions.

In the above, `a` is called an *accumulator*. The general idea is to move the operations you normally do *after* a recursive call into the next recursive call, by wrapping up the work outer calls have done "so far" and passing that on in an accumulator.

If `map` can be thought of as meaning "call `f` on every element of `l`, and return a list of the results", `map_acc` can be thought of as meaning "call `f` on every element of `l`, returning a list of the results combined with `a`, a list of results already produced".

Comment: Would it be ok ,instead of typing another function, to have the third parameter with a default value as an argument in the main function? Which gets modified once the first call is done.

Comment: @JuanGallostra Yep, that works (so long as you're careful about never mutating or returning values that might be bound to the default argument in some code paths).

Comment: tail call in map_acc should be map_acc(l[1:], f, b), because map takes only 2 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

This will be an example of the implementation of the built-in function map in tail recursion:

```
def map(func, ls, res=None):
    if res is None:
        res = []
    if not ls:
        return res
    res.append(func(ls[0]))
    return map(func, ls[1:], res)
```

But it will not solve the problem of python not having support of [TRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion) which mean that the call stack of each function call will be hold at all the time.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be tail recursive:

```
def map(l,f,x=[]):
    if l == []:
        return x
    else:
        return map(l[1:],f,x+[f(l[0])])
```

Or in more compact form:

```
def map(l,f,x=[]):
    return l and map(l[1:],f,x+[f(l[0])]) or x
```

Comment: using a mutable default argument is not a wise think to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: @mouand, I know this feature. It will not lead to any errors if you use the function in correct way.

Comment: Unless you call `my_list = map(empty_list, some_func); my_list.append(5)`. Now every further empty list will be mapped to [5].

Answer (score 0):

not really an answer, sorry, but another way to implement map is to write it in terms of a fold.  if you try, you'll find that it only comes out "right" with foldr; using foldl gives you a reversed list.  unfortunately, foldr isn't tail recursive, while foldl is.  this suggests that there's something more "natural" about rev_map (map that returns a reversed list).  unfortunately i am not well enough educated to take this any further (i suspect you might be able to generalise this to say that there is no solution that doesn't use an accumulator, but i personally don't see how to make the argument).