# Will a value that has a type with class constraints actually be a function at run time?

Tags: haskell

Consider the famous

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

Suppose that, to avoid the monomorphism restriction, this is annotated with:

```
fibs :: Num a => [a]
```

This seems to imply that at runtime, a list value `fibs` does not really exist, but rather a function that computes the list anew each time an element of `fibs` is picked?

The question is how such cases are actually handled in different Haskell implementations you know of.

--- ADDED ----
I feel that I must elaborate a bit more. Consider:

```
fibsInteger :: [Integer]
fibsInteger = 0: 1: zipWith (+) fibsInteger (tail fibsInteger)
```

and suppose during program execution the value

```
(fibsInteger !! 42)
```

needs to be evaluated. In that case I would expect that subsequent evaluations like that would find that the first 43 elements of `fibsInteger` are already evaluated. This implies also that `fibsInteger` itself and the first 42 tails of it are already in WHNF.

Yet that would not be possible with a polymorphic `fibs`, as far as I can see. FUZxxl's remark

> because a typeclass usually introduces a new argument containing a
>   dictionary with the functions of that typeclass

seems to support my view that a value like `fibs` effectively appears as function at runtime?

If this were so, then an application like `((maximum . map (fibs!!)) [100000 .. 101000] :: Integer)` shold take noticeably longer to evaluate than the non-polymorphic variant `((maximum . map (fibsInteger!!)) [100000 .. 101000] :: Integer)` because the first 100000 numbers will have to be recomputed each time.
(Unfortunately, I can't try this out at this time)

Comment: I'm sure someone will come along with a detailed explanation, but the term you want to google here is "thunk".

Comment: @MatrixFrog - unfortunately no, that wouldn't help much - that thunks are used in implementations of non-strict languages is not really news to me. The point is that when we restrict `fibs :: [Integer]` thunks in the list can be actually updated when, for example  `(fibs !! 42)` is evaluated. And my question is, if and how this can be done when `fibs` is polymorphic.

Comment: "Thanks to overloaded numeric literals, this has type `fibs :: Num a => [a]`". Actually thanks to the monomorphism restriction and type defaulting, it will have type `[Integer]`.

Comment: @sepp2k - yes that's correct. But suppose the type annotation is given explicitely. I'll edit the question accordingly.

Comment: The tail matches the return of fibs, thus sharing will occur and you get you O(n) behavior.

Comment: Time to abstract from what seems like an O(n) example (in the real world, complexity of + is not O(1), of course)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It depends on the implementation. In GHC, type classes are implemented using *dictionaries*. Let's say the `Num` class was defined like this (simplified for this example):

```
class Num a where
    fromInteger :: Integer -> a
    (+) :: a -> a -> a
```

Then it will be compiled as a "dictionary" data type:

```
data Num a = Num { fromInteger :: Integer -> a, plus :: a -> a -> a }
```

Anything with a `Num` constraint will get an extra argument for the dictionary, so for example `foo x = x + 1` will become:

```
foo :: Num a -> a -> a
foo num x = plus num x (fromInteger num 1)
```

So let's see how GHC compiles `fibs`, shall we?

```
$ cat Fibs.hs
module Fibs where
fibs :: Num a => [a]
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
$ ghc -c Fibs.hs -ddump-simpl

==================== Tidy Core ====================
Rec {
Fibs.fibs [Occ=LoopBreaker]
  :: forall a_abu. GHC.Num.Num a_abu => [a_abu]
[GblId, Arity=1]
Fibs.fibs =
  \ (@ a_akv) ($dNum_akw :: GHC.Num.Num a_akv) ->
    GHC.Types.:
      @ a_akv
      (GHC.Num.fromInteger
         @ a_akv $dNum_akw (GHC.Integer.smallInteger 0))
      (GHC.Types.:
         @ a_akv
         (GHC.Num.fromInteger
            @ a_akv $dNum_akw (GHC.Integer.smallInteger 1))
         (GHC.List.zipWith
            @ a_akv
            @ a_akv
            @ a_akv
            (GHC.Num.+ @ a_akv $dNum_akw)
            (Fibs.fibs @ a_akv $dNum_akw)
            (GHC.List.tail @ a_akv (Fibs.fibs @ a_akv $dNum_akw))))
end Rec }
```

If you squint a little, this is essentially

```
fibs :: Num a -> [a]
fibs num = fromInteger num 0
         : fromInteger num 1
         : zipWith (plus num) (fibs num) (tail (fibs num))
```

So for GHC, the answer is yes. As you suspected, this can have drastic implications on performance, as this destroys the sharing of `fibs` that this definition relies on, to the point where you get exponential runtime instead of linear<sup>1</sup>.

```
Prelude Fibs> :set +s
Prelude Fibs> fibs !! 30
832040
(3.78 secs, 912789096 bytes)
```

We can fix this problem by introducing sharing ourselves:

```
module SharedFibs where
fibs :: Num a => [a]
fibs = let f = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) f (tail f) in f
```

This is much better.

```
Prelude SharedFibs> :set +s
Prelude SharedFibs> fibs !! 30
832040
(0.06 secs, 18432472 bytes)
Prelude SharedFibs> fibs !! 100000
<huge number>
(2.19 secs, 688490584 bytes)
```

But it still has the same problem that `fibs` is not shared between separate calls. If you want this, you will have to specialize `fibs` to your desired number type in a `let` or `where`.

These sort of performance surprises is part of the reason why the dreaded [monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction) exists.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Ignoring the fact that `Integer` addition is not constant time.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Polymorphism can bring an additional performance burden (which I think is the question you are asking). In Thomas' answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964392/speed-comparison-with-project-euler-c-vs-python-vs-erlang-vs-haskell), making the type non-polymorphic reduced runtime from 36 to 11 seconds.

Your statement:

> This seems to imply that at runtime, a list value fibs does not really exist, but rather a function that computes the list anew each time an element of fibs is picked?

I'm not really sure what you mean here - you seem to be aware that it's lazy. You might be asking if Haskell considers this a "function declaration" or a "value declaration" - you can try using Template Haskell:

```
> runQ [d| fib = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fib (tail fib) |]
[ValD (VarP fib) ...
```

So it is a value declaration (ValD).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the list is infinite, thus it's impossible to generate the whole list before the program runs. As MatrixFrog already pointed out, `fibs` is a *thunk*. You can roughly imagine a thunk as a function that takes no argument and returns a value. The only difference is, that the pointer to the function is replaced by a pointer to the result afterwards, causing the result to be cached. This happens only in case of funcions that are not depending on any typeclass, because a typeclass usually introduces a new argument containing a dictionary with the functions of that typeclass (This process is sometimes called *reification*).

A long time I posted an answer to this [codegolf.SE question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2403/implement-lazy-lists-preferably-in-a-language-you-dont-know-well) containing an [own implementation](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1869832/lazy-list.tar.bz2) of thunks in C. The code is not very good, the list stuff is not separated very well from the thunk itself, but it's worth having a look.

Comment: This seems to indirectly support my view, see edited question.

Answer (score 0):

A function always involves the `(->)` type constructor, so it is not a function.  It's a value.  Functions are also values, but values are not functions, and that has nothing to do with laziness.  The key property of a function is that you can apply it.  Application has the type:

```
(a -> b) -> a -> b
```

Of course it is a lazy value and on the implementation level involves something called a thunk, but this is largely irrelevant to your question.  Thunks are an implementation detail.  Just because it is a lazily computed value doesn't turn it into a function.  Don't confuse evaluation with execution!  Functions in a language like C are not the same as function in Haskell.  Haskell uses the real mathematical notion of a function, which is completely unrelated to with which strategy things are executed on the machine level.

Comment: To put it differently, you don't have the slightest idea how it is *actually* implemented. Thank you for participating, nevertheless.