# Why does adding a polymorphic type signature degrade performance?

Tags: performance, haskell

Here's a simple function to compute Fibonacci numbers:

```
fib :: [Int]
fib = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fib (tail fib)
```

In ghci I can compute the series quickly. In fact, a bit of experimentation reveals that the computation runs in approximately linear time.

```
ghci> last $ take 100000 fib
354224848179261915075         -- takes under a second
```

If I change the type signature to be polymorphic instead:

```
fib :: Num a => [a]
fib = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fib (tail fib)
```

Then the algorithm becomes slower. In fact, it seems that it now runs in exponential time!

Does switching to a polymorphic type signature mean that the list being completely recomputed at each stage? If so, why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will a value that has a type with class constraints actually be a function at run time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7659845/will-a-value-that-has-a-type-with-class-constraints-actually-be-a-function-at-ru)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is because of the dictionary translation.

```
fib :: [Int]
```

is a top level constant.

But this:

```
fib :: Num a => [a]
fib = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fib (tail fib)
```

is just a top level function, which will be applied to a `Num` dictionary at runtime. Like so:

```
fib d = 1 : 1 : zipWith (d.+) (fib d) (tail (fib d))
```

So if you compile this without any optimizations, such that no specialization can happen, you'll end up with exponential time fib, as the list is rebuilt from scratch, on each function call -- it isn't a lazy data structure anymore.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, the polymorphic type signature means it's being recomputed at each stage. The core produced by ghc-7.4.2 with `-O2`:

```
lvl_rcZ :: GHC.Integer.Type.Integer
[GblId, Str=DmdType]
lvl_rcZ = __integer 1

Rec {
PolyFib.fib [Occ=LoopBreaker]
  :: forall a_a9W. GHC.Num.Num a_a9W => [a_a9W]
[GblId, Arity=1, Str=DmdType L]
PolyFib.fib =
  \ (@ a_aal) ($dNum_aam :: GHC.Num.Num a_aal) ->
    GHC.Types.:
      @ a_aal
      (GHC.Num.fromInteger @ a_aal $dNum_aam lvl_rcZ)
      (GHC.Types.:
         @ a_aal
         (GHC.Num.fromInteger @ a_aal $dNum_aam lvl_rcZ)
         (GHC.List.zipWith
            @ a_aal
            @ a_aal
            @ a_aal
            (GHC.Num.+ @ a_aal $dNum_aam)
            (PolyFib.fib @ a_aal $dNum_aam)
            (case PolyFib.fib @ a_aal $dNum_aam of _ {
               [] -> GHC.List.tail1 @ a_aal;
               : _ xs_abD -> xs_abD
             })))
end Rec }
```

The reason is that it's not feasible to cache a list of Fibonacci numbers for each type belonging to `Num`, and `fib` is explicitly a polymorphic value, hence it doesn't get cached at all.

If you want to cache it at least for the computation at each type, use a local list

```
pfibs :: Num a => [a]
pfibs = res
  where
    res = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) res (tail res)
```

does the caching for each computation (so `pfibs !! 500` e.g. is fast) since now the list is monomorphic in each computation. It will still be recomputed for each query (unless you bind it to a monomorphic name), but not for each single list element.

```
*PolyFib> pfibs !! 999999 :: Int
-4249520595888827205
(0.31 secs, 137462088 bytes)
```