# Puzzling performance/output behavior with rank-2 polymorphism in Haskell

Tags: performance, haskell, polymorphism, rank-n-types

The below code (annotated inline with locations) gives a minimal example of the puzzling behavior I'm experiencing.

Essentially, why does (2) result in terrible space/time performance while (1) does not?

The below code is compiled and run as follows on ghc version 8.4.3:
`ghc -prof -fprof-auto -rtsopts test.hs; ./test +RTS -p`

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}

import Debug.Trace

-- Not sure how to get rid of the record
data State = State {
    -- (0) If vstate :: Float, the extra "hello"s go away
    vstate :: forall a . (Fractional a) => a
}

step :: State -> State
step s =
    -- (1) one "hello" per step
    -- let vs = trace "hello" (vstate s) in
    -- s { vstate = vs `seq` vstate s }

    -- (2) increasing "hello"s per step
    s { vstate = (trace "hello" (vstate s)) `seq` vstate s }

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let initState = State { vstate = 0 }

    -- (3) step 3 times
    -- let res = step $ step $ step initState
    -- print $ vstate res

    -- (4) step 20 times to profile time/space performance
    let res = iterate step initState
    print $ vstate $ last $ take 20 res

    print "done"
```

a. With (1) and (3) commented in, compiled without `-O2`, the code only outputs "hello" three times, as I expect it to.

b. With (2) and (3) commented in, compiled without `-O2`, the code outputs "hello" eight times. It seems to output one additional "hello" per step. **I don't understand why this is happening.**

c. With (1) and (4) commented in, compiled without `-O2`, the code runs extremely fast.

d. With (2) and (4) commented in, compiled without `-O2`, the code runs very slowly, and the performance report (included below) shows that makes many more calls to `vstate` and uses much more memory than variant `c`. **I also don't understand why this is happening.**

e. With (2) and (4) commented in, compiled **with** `-O2`, the code behaves the same as variant `c`. So clearly ghc is able to optimize away whatever pathological behavior is happening in variant `d`.

Here is the profiling report for variant `c` (fast):

```
    Mon Aug 13 15:48 2018 Time and Allocation Profiling Report  (Final)

       partial +RTS -p -RTS

    total time  =        0.00 secs   (0 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
    total alloc =     107,560 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE MODULE           SRC                        %time %alloc

CAF         GHC.IO.Handle.FD <entire-module>              0.0   32.3
CAF         GHC.IO.Encoding  <entire-module>              0.0    3.1
main        Main             partial.hs:(24,1)-(35,16)    0.0   13.4
main.res    Main             partial.hs:32:9-36           0.0    1.6
step        Main             partial.hs:(15,1)-(18,36)    0.0    1.1
step.vs     Main             partial.hs:17:9-37           0.0   46.1


                                                                                         individual      inherited
COST CENTRE           MODULE                SRC                       no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

MAIN                  MAIN                  <built-in>                114          0    0.0    0.6     0.0  100.0
 CAF                  Main                  <entire-module>           227          0    0.0    0.1     0.0   52.2
  main                Main                  partial.hs:(24,1)-(35,16) 228          1    0.0    2.7     0.0   52.1
   vstate             Main                  partial.hs:11:5-10        230         20    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
    main.initState    Main                  partial.hs:25:9-40        239          0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
    main.res          Main                  partial.hs:32:9-36        234          0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
     step             Main                  partial.hs:(15,1)-(18,36) 235          0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
   main.initState     Main                  partial.hs:25:9-40        233          1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
   main.res           Main                  partial.hs:32:9-36        231          1    0.0    1.6     0.0   49.4
    step              Main                  partial.hs:(15,1)-(18,36) 232         19    0.0    1.1     0.0   47.8
     step.vs          Main                  partial.hs:17:9-37        236         19    0.0   46.1     0.0   46.7
      vstate          Main                  partial.hs:11:5-10        237        190    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.6
       main.initState Main                  partial.hs:25:9-40        238          0    0.0    0.6     0.0    0.6
 CAF                  Debug.Trace           <entire-module>           217          0    0.0    0.2     0.0    0.2
 CAF                  GHC.Conc.Signal       <entire-module>           206          0    0.0    0.6     0.0    0.6
 CAF                  GHC.IO.Encoding       <entire-module>           189          0    0.0    3.1     0.0    3.1
 CAF                  GHC.IO.Encoding.Iconv <entire-module>           187          0    0.0    0.2     0.0    0.2
 CAF                  GHC.IO.Handle.FD      <entire-module>           178          0    0.0   32.3     0.0   32.3
 CAF                  GHC.IO.Handle.Text    <entire-module>           176          0    0.0    0.1     0.0    0.1
 main                 Main                  partial.hs:(24,1)-(35,16) 229          0    0.0   10.7     0.0   10.7
```

Here is the profiling report for variant `d` (slow; without `-O2`):

```
    Mon Aug 13 15:25 2018 Time and Allocation Profiling Report  (Final)

       partial +RTS -p -RTS

    total time  =        1.48 secs   (1480 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
    total alloc = 1,384,174,472 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE    MODULE    SRC                        %time %alloc

step           Main      partial.hs:(15,1)-(21,60)   95.7   98.8
main.initState Main      partial.hs:25:9-40           3.0    1.2
vstate         Main      partial.hs:11:5-10           1.4    0.0


                                                                                      individual      inherited
COST CENTRE        MODULE                SRC                       no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

MAIN               MAIN                  <built-in>                114          0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
 CAF               Main                  <entire-module>           227          0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
  main             Main                  partial.hs:(24,1)-(35,16) 228          1    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
   vstate          Main                  partial.hs:11:5-10        230    1048575    1.4    0.0   100.0  100.0
    main.initState Main                  partial.hs:25:9-40        236          0    3.0    1.2     3.0    1.2
    main.res       Main                  partial.hs:32:9-36        234          0    0.0    0.0    95.7   98.8
     step          Main                  partial.hs:(15,1)-(21,60) 235          0   95.7   98.8    95.7   98.8
   main.initState  Main                  partial.hs:25:9-40        233          1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
   main.res        Main                  partial.hs:32:9-36        231          1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
    step           Main                  partial.hs:(15,1)-(21,60) 232         19    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF               Debug.Trace           <entire-module>           217          0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF               GHC.Conc.Signal       <entire-module>           206          0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF               GHC.IO.Encoding       <entire-module>           189          0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF               GHC.IO.Encoding.Iconv <entire-module>           187          0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF               GHC.IO.Handle.FD      <entire-module>           178          0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF               GHC.IO.Handle.Text    <entire-module>           176          0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 main              Main                  partial.hs:(24,1)-(35,16) 229          0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
```

Here are some notes/guesses/questions on why this is happening:

- What's the relationship of the degrading performance to the increasing "hello" count? The pathological version seems to output one more "hello" with each additional step. Why?
- I'm aware that polymorphism in Haskell is slow, as detailed in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145503/why-does-adding-a-polymorphic-type-signature-degrade-performance). That might be part of the problem, since the pathological behavior goes away when `vstate` is monomorphized as `vstate :: Float`. But I don't see why the lack of a let-binding, as in location (2), would cause such bad time/space performance.
- This is the minimal version of a performance bug in a larger codebase, which we fixed by "monomorphizing" floating-type numbers using `realToFrac` (the commit is [here](https://github.com/penrose/penrose/commit/eaa08fde6f1f61a71eac24d840f7a94a1815273c) in case anyone is curious). I know that compiling with `-O2` fixes the behavior in the minimal example, but I tried it in the larger codebase and it does not fix the performance issues. (The reason we need rank-2 polymorphism in the larger codebase is to use the `ad` library for autodiff.) Is there a more principled fix than using `realToFrac`, such as an inline specialization that can be applied?

Comment: I'd guess that in (1) `vs` gets a monomorphic type thanks to the Monomorphism Restriction. To confirm this, try to annotate `vs` as in `let vs :: Double ; vs = ...` and `let vs :: forall a. Fractional a => a ; vs = ...`. My guess is that the former is as fast as the program above (with variant (1) uncommented), while the latter is slow.

Comment: Are you sure this example is reproducing the real performance issue you're seeing? e.g. if I remove the `trace` calls, `c` and `d` both seem fast. You might have better luck doing a gvimdiff on the core output from a fast and slow version of your real code (compiled with optimizations, etc)

Comment: I doubt this is the problem, but `State` can be a `newtype`, which makes the wrapper free. You cannot, however, make do *without* a wrapper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`forall a . (Fractional a) => a` is a function type.**

It has two arguments, a type `(a :: *)` and an instance with type `Fractional a`. Whenever you see `=>`, it's a function operationally, and compiles to a function in GHC's core representation, and sometimes stays a function in machine code as well. The main difference between `->` and `=>` is that arguments for the latter cannot be explicitly given by programmers, and they are always filled in implicitly by instance resolution.

Let's see the fast `step` first:

```
step :: State -> State
step (State f) =
    let vs = trace "hello" f
    in State (vs `seq` f)
```

Here, `vs` has an undetermined `Fractional` type which defaults to `Double`. If you turn on `-Wtype-defaults` warning, GHC will point this out to you. Since `vs :: Double`, it's just a numeric value, which is captured by the returned *closure*. Right, `` vs `seq` f `` is a function, since it has a functional type `forall a . (Fractional a) => a`, and it's desugared to an actual lambda expression by GHC. This lambda abstracts over the two arguments, captures `vs` as free variable, and passes along both arguments to `f`.

So, each `step` creates a new function closure which captures a `vs :: Double`. If we call `step` three times, we get three closures with three `Double`s inside, each closure referring to the previous one. Then, when we write `vstate (step $ step $ step initState)`, we again default to `Double`, and GHC calls this closure with the `Fractional Double` instance. All the `vs`-es call previous closures with `Fractional Double`, but every `vs` is evaluated only once, because they are regular lazy `Double` values which are not recomputed.

However, if we enable `NoMonomorphismRestriction`, `vs` is generalized to `forall a. Fractional a => a`, so it becomes a function as well, and its calls are not memoized anymore. Hence, in this case the fast version behaves the same as the slow version.

Now, the slow `step`:

```
step :: State -> State
step (State f) = State ((trace "hello" f) `seq` f)
```

This has *exponential* number of calls in the number of steps, because `step f` calls `f` twice, and without optimizations no computation is shared, because both calls occur under a lambda. In `` (trace "hello" f) `seq` f ``, the first call to `f` defaults to `Fractional Double`, and the second call just passes along the implicit `Fractional a` instance as before.

If we switch on optimization, GHC observes that the first `f` call does not depend on the function parameters, and floats out `trace "hello" f` to a let-binding, resulting in pretty much the same code as in the fast version.