# Haskell recursion efficency

Tags: haskell, memory, recursion

I'm doing some of the [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) projects (not as homework, just for fun/learning), and I'm learning Haskell. One of the problems was to find the largest Collatz Sequence with the starting number under 1 million (http://projecteuler.net/problem=14)

So anyhow, I was able to do it, and my algorithm works and gets the right answer rather rapidly when compiled. However, it uses a 1000000 depth recursion.

So my question is: did I do this right? As is, is the the proper Haskell way to do it? How could I make it faster? Also, with memory usage, how is the recursion actually implemented on the low-level? As in how does it use memory?

(**SPOILER ALERT: Don't look at this if you want to solve Project Euler's problem #14 on your own without looking at the answer.**)

--haskell script
--problem: find the longest collatz chain for a number less than 2 million.

```
collatzLength x| x == 1 = 1
               | otherwise = 1 + collatzLength(nextStep x)


longestChain (num, numLength) bound counter
           | counter >= bound = (num, numLength)
           | otherwise = longestChain (longerOf (num,numLength)
             (counter,   (collatzLength counter)) ) bound (counter + 1)
           --I know this is a messy function, but I was doing this problem just 
           --for myself, so I didn't bother making some utility functions for it.
           --also, I split the big line in half to display on here nicer, would
           --it actually run with this line split?


longerOf (a1,a2) (b1,b2)| a2 > b2 = (a1,a2)
                        | otherwise = (b1,b2)

nextStep n | mod n 2 == 0 = (n `div` 2)
           | otherwise = 3*n + 1

main = print (longestChain (0,0) 1000000 1)
```

The program runs in about 7.5 seconds when compiled with -O2.

So, any advice/suggestions? I want to try to get the program to run faster with less memory usage, and I want to do it in a very Haskellian (that should be a word) way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would try making `collatzLength` iterative (tail recursive). Right now you build the result using recursion `1 + (1 + (1 + ...))`. Apply the same tail recursion technique that you have for `longestChain`.

Comment: http://hpaste.org/90090

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit to Answer Questions**

> did I do this right?

Almost, as the comments said, you build a big thunk of `1+(1+(1+...))` - use a strict accumulator instead or a higher-level function that handles things for you.  There are other minor things like defining a function to compare the second element instead of using `maximumBy (comparing snd)` but that's more stylistic.

> As is, is the the proper Haskell way to do it?

It is acceptably idiomatic Haskell code.

> How could I make it faster?

See my below benchmarks.  The extremely common answers for Euler performance questions are:

- Use -O2 (as you did)
- Try -fllvm (GHC NCG is sub-optimal)
- Use worker/wrappers to reduce arguments or, in your case, leverage an accumulator.
- Use fast/unboxable types (Int when you can instead Integer, Int64 if needed for portability, etc).
- Use `rem` instead of `mod` when all the values are positive.  For your case it is also useful to know or discover that `div` tends to compile to something that is slower than `quot`.

> Also, with memory usage, how is the recursion actually implemented on the low-level?
>   As in how does it use memory?

Both these questions are very broad.  Complete answers would likey need to address lazy evaluation, tail call optimization, worker transformations, garbage collection, etc.  I suggest you explore these answers in more depth over time (or hope someone here makes the complete answer I'm avoiding).

**Original Post - Benchmark numbers**

Original:

```
$ ghc -O2 so.hs ; time ./so
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( so.hs, so.o )
Linking so ...
(837799,525)

real    0m5.971s
user    0m5.940s
sys 0m0.019s
```

Use a worker function with an accumulator for `collatzLength`:

```
$ ghc -O2 so.hs ; time ./so
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( so.hs, so.o )
Linking so ...
(837799,525)

real    0m5.617s
user    0m5.590s
sys 0m0.012s
```

Use `Int` and not defaulting to `Integer` - it's also easier to read with type signatures!

```
$ ghc -O2 so.hs ; time ./so
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( so.hs, so.o )
Linking so ...
(837799,525)

real    0m2.937s
user    0m2.932s
sys 0m0.001s
```

Use `rem` and not `mod`:

```
$ ghc -O2 so.hs ; time ./so
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( so.hs, so.o )
Linking so ...
(837799,525)

real    0m2.436s
user    0m2.431s
sys 0m0.001s
```

Use `quotRem` and not `rem` then `div`:

```
$ ghc -O2 so.hs ; time ./so
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( so.hs, so.o )
Linking so ...
(837799,525)

real    0m1.672s
user    0m1.669s
sys 0m0.002s
```

This is all very much like a previous question: [Speed comparison with Project Euler: C vs Python vs Erlang vs Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964392/speed-comparison-with-project-euler-c-vs-python-vs-erlang-vs-haskell/6964760#6964760)

EDIT: and yes, as Daniel Fischer suggests, using bit ops of `.&.` and `shiftR` improves on `quotRem`:

```
$ ghc -O2 so.hs ; time ./so
(837799,525)

real    0m0.314s
user    0m0.312s
sys 0m0.001s
```

Or you can just use LLVM and let it do it's magic (NB this version uses `quotRem` still)

```
$ time ./so
(837799,525)

real    0m0.286s
user    0m0.283s
sys 0m0.002s
```

LLVM actually does well, so long as you avoid the hideousness that is `mod`, and optimizes the guard-based code using either `rem` or `even` equally well as the hand-optimized `.&.` with `shiftR`.

For a result that is around 20x faster than the original.

EDIT: People are surprised that quotRem performs as well as bit manipulation in the face of `Int`.   The code is included, but I'm not clear on the surprise: just because something is possibly negative doesn't mean you can't handle it with very similar bit manipulations that could be of identical cost on the right hardware.  All three versions of `nextStep` seem to be performing identically (`ghc -O2 -fforce-recomp -fllvm`, ghc version 7.6.3, LLVM 3.3, x86-64).

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns, UnboxedTuples #-}

import Data.Bits

collatzLength :: Int -> Int
collatzLength x| x == 1    = 1
               | otherwise = go x 0
 where
    go 1 a  = a + 1
    go x !a = go (nextStep x) (a+1)


longestChain :: (Int, Int) -> Int -> Int -> (Int,Int)
longestChain (num, numLength) bound !counter
   | counter >= bound = (num, numLength)
   | otherwise = longestChain (longerOf (num,numLength) (counter, collatzLength counter)) bound (counter + 1)
           --I know this is a messy function, but I was doing this problem just 
           --for myself, so I didn't bother making some utility functions for it.
           --also, I split the big line in half to display on here nicer, would
           --it actually run with this line split?


longerOf :: (Int,Int) -> (Int,Int) -> (Int,Int)
longerOf (a1,a2) (b1,b2)| a2 > b2 = (a1,a2)
                        | otherwise = (b1,b2)
{-# INLINE longerOf #-}

nextStep :: Int -> Int
-- Version 'bits'
nextStep n = if 0 == n .&. 1 then n `shiftR` 1 else 3*n+1
-- Version 'quotRem'
-- nextStep n = let (q,r) = quotRem n 2 in if r == 0 then q else 3*n+1
-- Version 'almost the original'
-- nextStep n | even n = quot n 2
--            | otherwise  = 3*n + 1
{-# INLINE nextStep #-}


main = print (longestChain (0,0) 1000000 1)
```

Comment: Now use `n .&. 1 == 0` and ``n `shiftR` 1`` instead of `quotRem`.

Comment: @DanielFischer I read many times that a decent compiler should do such an optimization itself. Do you know how it is with GHC (perhaps with the LLVM backend)? Does using explicit bit shift operations really help?

Comment: @PetrPudlák GHC has not yet been taught many of such optimisations, too few people working on it, their time is spent with higher-level optimisations and type system trickery, it does not not do that by itself (so far). The LLVM backend does that optimisation when you use the right type (and last I checked, only for `quot/rem`, not for `div/mod`). But of course, with `Int`, it has to take into account the possibility of negative numbers, so you can beat it (not by much) using the domain-knowledge that only positive numbers occur [unless `Int` is 32 bits, in which case you have overflow].

Comment: At least on my box, even with the LLVM backend, simply shifting beats the LLVM optimisation (by a surprisingly large margin, ~25%), since LLVM doesn't know that no negative numbers occur. The difference disappears when using `Word`.

Comment: @Thomas How bit operations with LLVM compares with `quotRem` with LLVM? Can you add that timing info too.

Comment: @Satvik they are indistinguishable.  I assume LLVM recognizes the assembly equivalent of `quotRem x 2` and rewrites it.

Comment: Thomas, indistinguishable with `Int`? That would surprise me a little (not as much as the large difference I got here), since it would need to cater for negative dividends. For `Word`, it is to be expected to be identical, since then the division is a single shift.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson My surprise is because a) To account for negative numbers, you need two shifts and one add, while for non-negative numbers, you're golden with just one shift. Well, I would expect that to make a small difference, if it is at all measurable, except that b) I got a ~25% difference between just masking and shifting by hand and `quotRem` or `even` + `quot` with the LLVM backend. (And I just checked, with the manual shift-add-shift signed division by 2, I get pretty much the same time as LLVM + `quot(Rem)`, so the difference is due to the additional add and shift, at least ...

Comment: ... almost all of it.) So I'm a bit surprised that something that makes a (surprisingly) large difference on my box makes apparently none on yours. Could be the different CPUs, could be different compilers. (Of course it's possible that your LLVM notices that the division is only done on even numbers, so the plain single shift suffices also for negative numbers. But that would also surprise me a little, since mine [3.2] doesn't.)

Comment: @WillNess On a 32-bit system, _this particular problem_ would lead to overflow that leads to infinite negative cycles when using `Int`. As it so happens, for this particular problem, the overflows that happen when using `Word` on a 32-bit system wouldn't change the computed answer, so one could cheat and use `Word` for speed on a 32-bit system. But if one doesn't want to cheat on a 32-bit system, one needs `Int64`/`Word64` or `Integer`.