# Speeding up LARGE number of string comparisons in python

Tags: python, string, hash

I have a large number (several millions) of strings of a predetermined size (several hundred chars). One of the things I am interested in is to calculate a frequency table for these strings. Not so surprisingly the process takes a long time on my test runs.

I was concerned about the dictionary size, but it appears as there is no theoretical upper limit in Python besides the physical available memory. So I could technically create a large dictionary and there should not be any rehashing necessary. Is this a correct assumption?

Additionally would switching to [another hash function](https://github.com/flier/pyfasthash) (perhaps with longer output than 32 bits) than the builtin hash for strings make a significant difference in terms of hash calculation and collisions?

Lastly, I read [this interesting question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964392/speed-comparison-with-project-euler-c-vs-python-vs-erlang-vs-haskell) and now I wonder whether or not running things with pypy or one of the other python optimizations suggested would make a significant difference in this case.

I am rather new to Python and haven't got all the bits in place yet. So I'd appreciate if you keep that in mind in your answers.

Comment: Why not dump the whole thing into a relational database and let an index do the job?

Comment: @DanieleBernardini because this analysis will be a part in a pipeline that'll run on a cloud service. I don't think it'll be a feasible solution to create a new db every time somebody runs the analysis

Comment: This seems like a good use for some non-relational database options, something like Hadoop and Map-Reduce.